# How to batch process entire folder with ffmpeg? a batch script that will scan currently run folder

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have this code but it is not working

I want batch script to scan currently run directory and batch process the MP4 files in that directory

But first i want it to create a new directory called as `newfiles` and put the processed files in that folder with the same name

Please help me to fix this batch script ty

```
md "%~dp0\newfiles"
for %%a in (%~dp0\"*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p "newfiles\%~dp0%%a.mp4"
pause
```

The code is not creating a new directory not batch process the mp4 files in that directory (the directory that is batch script executed)

**ok i have solved the question as below**

```
md "%~dp0\newfiles"
for %%a in (%~dp0\"*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: 'It is not working' does not satisfactorily define your problem, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49159032/edit) accordingly.

Comment: MonsterMMORPG, as your problem was simply a self inflicted typo, it would probably be advisable to delete your post.

Comment: You should also get rid of all occurrences of `%~dp0` unless you explicitly want the drive+path of the directory containing the .bat script to be the working directory.  If you intend to keep it, then include it within the quotation marks in your `for` parenthetical.  `for %%a in ("%~dp0\*.mp4")` so your script won't break if `%~dp0` contains a space.  If not quoted, your pathname will be split on spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for your script, as requested in your question.

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "%~dp0*.mp4" Exit /B
CD /D "%~dp0"
If Not Exist "newfiles\" MD "newfiles" 
For %%A In (*.mp4) Do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p "newfiles\%%A"
```